# Mongodb: Combine result queries from multiple colllections

Tags: mongodb

#### Collection-1 'Office-Encounters'

```
{'_id': '1111', 'type': 'OE', 'pcode': 'P1212', 'rank': 11}
{'_id': '2222', 'type': 'OE', 'pcode': 'P2323', 'rank': 25}
{'_id': '3333', 'type': 'OE', 'pcode': 'P1212', 'rank': 18}
{'_id': '4444', 'type': 'OE', 'pcode': 'P2323', 'rank': 10}
```

#### Collection-2 'LabEncounters'

```
{'_id': '5555', 'type': 'LE', 'pcode': 'P1212', 'rank': 9}
{'_id': '6666', 'type': 'LE', 'pcode': 'P2323', 'rank': 7}
{'_id': '7777', 'type': 'LE', 'pcode': 'P1212', 'rank': 15}
{'_id': '8888', 'type': 'LE', 'pcode': 'P2323', 'rank': 3}
```

I would like to get all documents where 'pcode' is P2323 and sorted by 'rank'. The final result should look like below:

```
[
    {'_id': '8888', 'type': 'LE', 'pcode': 'P2323', 'rank': 3},
    {'_id': '6666', 'type': 'LE', 'pcode': 'P2323', 'rank': 7},
    {'_id': '4444', 'type': 'OE', 'pcode': 'P2323', 'rank': 10},
    {'_id': '2222', 'type': 'OE', 'pcode': 'P2323', 'rank': 25}
]
```

What's the best way to get the result like above? Thanks!

Comment: The best way is to make 2 queries and concatenate them. What language are you using?

Comment: I am using Java to query the documents. If there are just collections, I could have make 2 queries, but actually there are 7 collections I need to deal with.